# pktgen cannot find Mellanox port

Tags: dpdk

## Setup

- Pktgen version 21.01.0
- DPDK version 20.11
- OS: ubuntu 18.04
- NIC: Mellanox

```
driver: mlx5_core
version: 5.1-2.5.8
firmware-version: 16.28.2006 (MT_0000000012)
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:03:00.1
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

## Issue

When I run `dpdk-testpmd` in dpdk 20.11 and `./dpdk-devbind -s`, it can find mlx port

```
Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:03:00.0 'MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5] 1017' if=ens1f0 drv=mlx5_core unused=vfio-pci
0000:03:00.1 'MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5] 1017' if=ens1f1 drv=mlx5_core unused=vfio-pci
0000:05:00.0 'I210 Gigabit Network Connection 1533' if=enp5s0 drv=igb unused=vfio-pci *Active*
0000:06:00.0 'I210 Gigabit Network Connection 1533' if=enp6s0 drv=igb unused=vfio-pci
0000:07:00.0 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' if=enp7s0f0 drv=ixgbe unused=vfio-pci
0000:07:00.1 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' if=enp7s0f1 drv=ixgbe unused=vfio-pci
```

```
$sudo build/app/dpdk-testpmd -c7 --vdev=net_pcap0,iface=eth0 --vdev=net_pcap1,iface=eth1 -- -i --nb-cores=2 --nb-ports=2 --total-num-mbufs=2048

EAL: Detected 24 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:03:00.0 (socket 0)
mlx5_pci: Size 0xFFFF is not power of 2, will be aligned to 0x10000.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:03:00.1 (socket 0)
mlx5_pci: Size 0xFFFF is not power of 2, will be aligned to 0x10000.
open_iface_live(): Couldn't open eth0: eth0: No such device exists (SIOCGIFHWADDR: No such device)
open_single_iface(): Couldn't open interface eth0
vdev_probe(): failed to initialize net_pcap0 device
open_iface_live(): Couldn't open eth1: eth1: No such device exists (SIOCGIFHWADDR: No such device)
open_single_iface(): Couldn't open interface eth1
vdev_probe(): failed to initialize net_pcap1 device
EAL: Bus (vdev) probe failed.
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Interactive-mode selected
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_0>: n=2048, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc
Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
Port 0: 98:03:9B:06:AB:34
Configuring Port 1 (socket 0)
Port 1: 98:03:9B:06:AB:35
Checking link statuses...
Done
testpmd> quit
```

But when I run `pktgen`, it doesn't work.

```
$sudo ./Builddir/app/pktgen -c 0xff -n 3 -a 0000:03:00.1 -- -p 0x1 -P -m "[1:2].0"

Copyright (c) <2010-2020>, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved. Powered by DPDK
EAL: Detected 24 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created

*** Copyright (c) <2010-2020>, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
*** Pktgen  created by: Keith Wiles -- >>> Powered by DPDK <<<

 Port: Name         IfIndex Alias        NUMA  PCI

!PANIC!: *** Did not find any ports to use ***
PANIC in pktgen_config_ports():
*** Did not find any ports to use ***
6: [./Builddir/app/pktgen(+0x977a) [0x556f614b477a]]
5: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f1721223bf7]]
4: [./Builddir/app/pktgen(+0x9319) [0x556f614b4319]]
3: [./Builddir/app/pktgen(+0x31fa7) [0x556f614dcfa7]]
2: [/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eal.so.21(__rte_panic+0xc5) [0x7f172221d285]]
1: [/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eal.so.21(rte_dump_stack+0x2e) [0x7f172223ef2e]]
Aborted
```

## [Update-1]

I have found `librte_net_mlx5.so` existing in the system:

```
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_mlx5.so.21.0
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_mlx5.so.21
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_mlx5.so
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dpdk/pmds-21.0/librte_net_mlx5.so.21.0
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dpdk/pmds-21.0/librte_net_mlx5.so.21
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dpdk/pmds-21.0/librte_net_mlx5.so
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_mlx5.a
/home/dpdk-20.11/build/drivers/librte_net_mlx5.so.21.0
/home/dpdk-20.11/build/drivers/librte_net_mlx5.so.21
/home/dpdk-20.11/build/drivers/librte_net_mlx5.so
/home/dpdk-20.11/build/drivers/librte_net_mlx5.a.p
/home/dpdk-20.11/build/drivers/librte_net_mlx5.so.21.0.p
/home/dpdk-20.11/build/drivers/librte_net_mlx5.a
```

I tried add `-d librte_net_mlx5.so` as **@Vipin Varghese**'s advice, and got following output:

```
$sudo ./Builddir/app/pktgen -c 0xff -n 3 -a 0000:03:00.1 -d librte_net_mlx5.so -- -p 0x1 -P -m "[1:2].0"

EAL: Detected 24 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:03:00.1 (socket 0)
mlx5_pci: Size 0xFFFF is not power of 2, will be aligned to 0x10000.
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created

*** Copyright (c) <2010-2020>, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
*** Pktgen  created by: Keith Wiles -- >>> Powered by DPDK <<<

 Port: Name         IfIndex Alias        NUMA  PCI
    0: mlx5_pci       11                   0   15b3:1017/03:00.1

Initialize Port 0 -- TxQ 1, RxQ 1
MBUF: error setting mempool handler
!PANIC!: Cannot create mbuf pool (Default RX  0:0) port 0, queue 0, nb_mbufs 4096, socket_id 0: Invalid argument
PANIC in pktgen_mbuf_pool_create():
Cannot create mbuf pool (Default RX  0:0) port 0, queue 0, nb_mbufs 4096, socket_id 0: Invalid argument
6: [./Builddir/app/pktgen(+0x977a) [0x55fd3145f77a]]
5: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f5479069bf7]]
4: [./Builddir/app/pktgen(+0x9319) [0x55fd3145f319]]
3: [./Builddir/app/pktgen(+0x3198b) [0x55fd3148798b]]
2: [/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eal.so.21(__rte_panic+0xc5) [0x7f547a063285]]
1: [/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eal.so.21(rte_dump_stack+0x2e) [0x7f547a084f2e]]
Aborted
```

Comment: Since you are using DPDK `20.11` which uses `ninja-meson`, one should ensure you have `mxl5` driver built. By default it will not be built, which leads to device PMD probe failure. Check your install folder for `librte_net_mx*`. Please confirm whether you have built the driver?

Comment: are there any updates from your end?

Comment: if the answer has solved your issue or helped you understand the problem, accept and upvote please

Comment: I have tried your advice and update the content. `pktgen` can not find `librte_net_mlx5.so` while the `.so` file exists.

Comment: thanks for your reply, `pktgen` not finding `librte_net_mxl5.so` when it exists simply means `pktgen is not built with right DPDK`. Feel free to connect on skype to debug.

Comment: as explained in comment and answer one can check if the DPDK used for `pktgen` is getting build with `pkg-config --cflags --libs --static libdpdk  | grep -i mxl5`. If its missing `pktgen is not build with mxl5`. Once again I offer online debug

Comment: waiting for your updates.

Comment: There is a typo, `mxl5`(x) `mlx5`(√), which leads to the missing file error. The new output has been posted.

Comment: So with option `-d librte_net_mlx5.so` the device is identified. Thank you for the update, I will update the answer, please `accept` and `upvote`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is evident the `pktgen` utility is

1. either not built with Mellanox PMD mlx5 based on the logs
2. or pktgen is not passed shared library for initlailizing MLX5 PMD

Since the DPDK used for building is DPDK version 20.11. The probability of pktgen build with the shared library is high. Passing eal argument as `-d librte_net_mlx5.so` should resolve the shared library issue.

Reason for not suggesting static library path is because of the logs of testpmd shows MLX5 is identified while eth0 and eth1 are non-existing interface and skipping PCAP PMD

```
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:03:00.0 (socket 0)
mlx5_pci: Size 0xFFFF is not power of 2, will be aligned to 0x10000.
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:03:00.1 (socket 0)
mlx5_pci: Size 0xFFFF is not power of 2, will be aligned to 0x10000.
```

[EDIT-1] requested for the proper details in comments too, none available.

[EDIT-2] to check if PKTGEN 21.01 is built with MXL5 PMD, in console check

1. `pkg-config --cflags --libs --static libdpdk  | grep -i mlx5`
2. `nm [pktgen-application] | grep -i mlx5`

. Based on the updated logs, `pktgen` is not build with DPDK which is placed in `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: as per the latest update, interfaces are identified with option `-d` please accept and upvote.